# Where are the environment variables used by Debezium Kafka connect set

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, debezium

The debezium kafka connect command is : `docker run -it --rm --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka --link mysql:mysql debezium/connect:0.9`

```
Plugins are loaded from /kafka/connect
Using the following environment variables:
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=172.17.0.4
ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
```

How do I configure these environment variables ? Where is it getting the values from ?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I configure these environment variables ?

All those `-e` values are setting environment variables. `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` should be set to `kafka:9092`, not an IP address if you are linking containers.

> Where is it getting the values from ?

Not sure I understand the question. You need to provide them. They are all "from" the `connect-distributed.properties` file of Kafka - http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

---

I suggest you use Docker Compose rather than `docker run` with deprecated `--link` option

https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/tutorial/docker-compose-mysql.yaml